# How do use a FireBreath plugin in a FireFox Extension (.XPI)?

Tags: firefox-addon, npapi, firebreath, xpi

I have written a multiplat addon which has been tested under both Chrome and Firefox. The testing was done using the default html file Firebreath generates, installing the DLL via regsvr32.

I would like to package this addon so that Firefox users can install it through the addon-manager through an XPI and use it in my extension. I have accomplished this in Chrome easily by packaging the DLL, backgroundpage.html into the CRX.

My understanding is that the Firebreath DLL has to be injected into the DOM of the XUL (browserOverlay.xul) which in turn can use the JS (borwserOverlay.js) to call the functions from the DLL.

I am unclear how to inject the DLL itself within the XUL, so far I have tried

```xml
<html:object id="myPlugin" type="application/x-betaplugin" width="300" height="300">
</html:object>
```

Where the DLL is called npBetaplugin.dll within the components directory if the XPI.

Comment: it is unclear from your question if you're just trying to package a NPAPI plugin inside a XPI or if you actually want to create an extension that *uses* said plugin as well.

Comment: It would be the latter, I am trying to create a Firefox extension that uses the already developed Firebreath plugin. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way works for me:

```xml
<vbox style="height:0;">
    <html:embed type="application/x-my-plugin" id="my-plugin" style="height:0;"/>
</vbox>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this out and let you know!

Comment: ok i added the namespace  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" and it worked